# Is it safe to use a non-atomic boolean without a mutex for control flow across threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

There are a number of related questions, but this question is arguably more specific.

Consider the following sample program, note that the `bool` is just an ordinary `bool`.

When I run it, it achieves the desired effect: after the user presses `Enter`, `hello world` will cease to print.

If I require only that `bar2()` **eventually** starts returning immediately after `run` is to `false`, is the logic below **guaranteed** to be safe by the standard?

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <unistd.h>


bool run = true;

void bar2() {
    // Is this check safe without a lock?
    if (!run) return;
    printf("hello world\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
void bar() {
    while (true) {
        bar2();
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(){
    std::thread(bar).detach();
    getchar();
    run = false;
    // Prevent main from exiting.
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: I would cowardly stick to an `unsigned char` (which should be equivalent to a `bool` on most architectures) :-( ...

Comment: Leave volatile aside - it has no impact

Comment: @DieterLücking, I removed it.

Comment: @DieterLücking Good point. And BTW why not making it an [`atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I prefer the simpler semantics of a simple `bool` provided that I have some guarantee that is it safe. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no guarantee by the standard that without synchronization or ordering guarantees given by e.g. `std::atomic` the other thread will ever see the write to `run`.

As a matter of fact the compiler would be perfectly fine to only check once that `write` is true and since the thread itself never writes to it cache the value without ever reloading it. Now practically speaking with all the c library calls going on the compiler generally cannot know that none of functions writes to `run` and under x86 you don't have to worry about not seeing updates from other processors to memory, so it will in practice work (and even under other architectures a context switch would probably resolve the problem).

But if you're talking purely from the standard's point of view? No guarantees whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly the case that the standard makes no guarantees of how this code will behave. The testing and setting of the `run` variable are not properly sequenced. As a consequence, relying on the order of setting and testing constitutes undefined behaviour.

The question of what a "real world" compiler will actually do is less easy. There are several things a compiler could reasonably do which would cause this program to fail. It could:

1. Detect the UB and institute its own implentation-specific course of action, which might work as you wanted, or not. At least if you test it, you will find out which.
2. Make the assumption that UB has not occurred, and delete the `if(!run)` test from the program, since without the UB it can never have any effect.
3. Observe that the `run` variable is never tested after it was set, and delete the `run=false`, since it can never have any effect. [This may involve assuming no UB.]

If it was my choice, I wouldn't rely on this code. I would use the capabilities provided by the standard and write conforming behaviour.

Answer (score -6):

yes, it is completely safe. most processors have 32 bit pipelines.

Comment: This seems to be a bit heuristic though. What if a processor did *not* have a 32-bit pipeline?

Comment: Assuming you're targeting PC architecture, I doubt you'd ever come across something with less than a 32 bit pipeline.

Comment: There is no guarantee that you will ever see the write to `run` so this is completely wrong and has nothing to do whatsoever with pipelines (and what does 32-bit pipeline mean anyhow? Processor pipelines are denoted in stages not bit!) In practice though assuming the compiler doesn't remove the load of `run` at all (it's perfectly valid for it to do so and I'm surprised it doesn't happen actually!) you will see the change after the first context switch.